# UNITY 3D | Can't drag HealthBar canvas object into GameObject HealthBar reference

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, reference, gameobject

I created an object "Health Bar" into my canvas and attached my HealthBar script to it:

[HealthBar Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNqgO.png)

Now I want to reference this Health Bar into my Monster that i'm spawning but it doesnt let me insert it into the public reference:

[Reference in object not accepting HealthBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHjwi.png)

Here is the code of my HealthBar script :

```
 public Slider slider;
 public void SetMaxHealth(int health)
 {
     slider.maxValue = health;
     slider.value = health;
 }
 public void SetHealth(int health)
 {
     slider.value = health;
 }
```

and here is the code of my MonsterManager:

```
 public int maxHealth = 100;
 public int currentHealth;
 public HealthBar healthBar;
 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {
     currentHealth = maxHealth;
     healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
     healthBar = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<HealthBar>();
 }
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
     {
         TakeDamage(20);
     }
     
 }
 void TakeDamage(int damage)
 {
     currentHealth -= damage;
     healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you're spawning a monster, I assume you mean you're instantiating a monster prefab into your scene.

Prefabs don't accept references to scene items, for the most part. There are was around this, but, for simplicity, let's just treat that as true.

With that in mind, the laziest way to resolve your issue is to find the health bar when the monster is spawned.

```cs
private HealthBar healthBar;

void Start()
{
    healthBar = GameObject.Find("Canvas/HealthBar");
    currentHealth = maxHealth;
    healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    healthBar = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<HealthBar>();
}
```

While this should work for you, it would be far better to find the health bar once and cache the reference. You would do this in something like a game manager, so when your monster runs it's `Start` method, it can simple get the reference from the game manager.

Comment: Yes you're right, I got an object called Spawner that instantiate my monsters.
I didn't know prefabs didnt accept scene items as references. Thank you for that.

Just to clarify the lazy way, if i'm trying to find an object in a Canvas, I have to tell it the entire path .find("Canvas/HealthBar")? Because I tried this way with only Find("HealthBar") but it didn't work.

So if I understand well the better option, I should do the .Find() in my some Manager so it only finds it once, and then calling it form my monsters so it saves ressources?

Comment: you can also put your image in your prefab and when instantiated set its parent to canvas, or set the canvas to world and put it in your prefab.

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll try different options and pick the one that suits the best.
Can you actually make more than one canvas in a scene so one is set to world and the other one stays in the UI ?

Comment: @JesseVANKERREBROUCK yep, you can have multiple canvasses in a scene. And per your earlier question, again yes, you’d want to look for an object in your scene once, and then cache that reference.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign scene variables to your prefab. You can put a canvas in your monster prefab and set its render mode to World. Then, when you instantiate your monsters, you must assign the camera variable of your canvas to the game camera. I suggest you to read [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/using-a-few-hundred-world-space-canvases-is-killing-performance.1140514/):

> From my experience, many world space canvases are faster than one big overlay that is constantly dirtied.

So it seems like using multiple world canvases is a good solution.

Comment: Alright thanks for confirming that. I'll try to set a multiple canses correctly :)

Comment: what do you seek?